# MySQL Multiple Group by with Dates

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have the following Database with example content:
[image: Database with content]

Now I want for a certain siteid for every weekday (Monday, ..., Sunday) for every tsegment-TIME (date independend) on this day the average category.

I have to parse the date from tstamp or tsegment. That basically work. 
Then I have to parse the time - that does not work. Don't know why.
I surmise it is because of the group by Weekday. But I do not know how to solve it.

That is my query:

```html
SELECT 
siteid, 
DAYNAME(STR_TO_DATE(tstamp, "%Y-%m-%d")) as Day,
STR_TO_DATE(tsegment,'%h:%i:%s') as Segment, 
AVG(category)

FROM `ITODDB_Occupancy` 

WHERE siteid = 350 

GROUP BY
Segment, Day
```

The result is

[image]

I want output like this:

```html
siteid    Day     Segment    AVG(Category)
350       Monday  11:10:00  3.987
350       Monday  11:15:00  2.123
350       Tuesday 08:00:00  3.999
350       Tuesday 09:35:00  2.500
...      ...      ...      ...
350       Sunday  03:45:00  1.432
350       Sunday  03:55:00  1.555
```

Comment: I would strongly encourage you to use the native date date types

Answer (score 0):

From what I've seen and worked with, the `TIMESTAMP` type can be somewhat wonky with `STR_TO_DATE`.  Instead, use a combination of `FROM_UNIXTIME`/`DATE_FORMAT`

`DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('2016-01-20T11:30:20'), '%h:%i:%s')`

That should give you what you need.

---

**Example:**

```html
SELECT 
siteid, 
DAYNAME(STR_TO_DATE(tstamp, "%Y-%m-%d")) as Day,
DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(tsegment), '%h:%i:%s') as Segment, 
AVG(category)

FROM `ITODDB_Occupancy` 

WHERE siteid = 350 

GROUP BY
Segment, Day
```

Comment: Hi, thakns for your anwer, but the output does not change. the time is still NULL

Comment: For now I just use `SUBSTRING_INDEX(tsegment, 'T', '-1'`

Comment: I just changed my answer to something that should work.  Give that a try.